# Kotlin: Passing HashMap with multiple value types into function

Tags: java, android, constructor, hashmap

I have a HashMap that looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "George",
    "weeks": [
        {
            "checked": true,
            "days": [
                {
                    "checked": true,
                    "exercises": [
                        {
                            "exercise": "Bench Press",
                            "sets": [
                                {
                                    "weight": 300,
                                    "reps": 20
                                },
                                {
                                    "weight": 400,
                                    "reps": 30
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So I thought I could pass it into the constructor of a class like so:

```
data class Gainer(val weeks: ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Long>>>>>>>>?, val name: String?) {
```

However, I am getting this error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Expected a List, but got a class java.lang.String (found in field 'weeks.[0].days.[0].exercises.[0].exercise')`

I am guessing I get this error because when I specify `Hashmap<String, ArrayList ...>` It is expecting `String` as the key type and `ArrayList` as the Value type. However, sometimes I set a `boolean` as one of the values and an `ArrayList` as a different value. I'm not sure how to specify multiple value types.

edit: What I am passing in isn't actually json data like what is shown. It is technically a documentSnapshot. I am getting it from Firestore. Sorry, I should have clarified that better.

Comment: Why do you use so complicated structure? I think it's much better to serialise it in data class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always use **Json to Kotlin Class Plugin**

Json to Kotlin Class is a plugin that make it easier to create POJOs from json file, and it will solve your problem creating your data classes. 

**You can see the usage in this gif:**

[image: Json to Kotlin Class Plugin gif]

You should download and add on your Android Studio or IntelliJ IDE as a plugin
 
Here is the link for download ~>
[Json to Kotlin Class](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-) 

It saves my life!

Answer (score 0):

one thing that might be helpful from Java perspective to handle multi-level hashmap;

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<String, Object>()
```

as in java `Object` is parent class for all, so that passing `Object` as value in map can cater any level of map.